# Let $p$ be a prime. Then for every integer $a$ there is an integer $x$ such that $x^3 \equiv a \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $p$ be a prime. Then for every integer $a$ there is an integer $x$ such that $x^3 \equiv a \pmod p$.

I prove it using a Fermat little’s theorem but I want help with counterexample. We know that if $p$ is a prime number, then for any integer $a$, the number $p^a − a$ is an integer multiple of $p$. Hence, it is not always true.

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. As an elementary counterexample, take $ a = 2$ and $ p = 7 $.

Comment: consider $ax \equiv 1 \mod{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The map $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection mod $p$ iff $\gcd(3,p-1)=1$.